# Woocommerce Tax calculating issues (wrong price amount per line)

Tags: php, woocommerce, tax

WooCommerce calculates the VAT (in this case 20%) per line (wrong), but really should calculate VAT per item (right).

For example, we have a product that is 0.13p (excl VAT), which shows as 0.16p (inc VAT) on the frontend. This is fine as 0.13p + 20% = 0.156p and is rounded up to 0.16p. If you add 5 of these to the cart you would expect to see 0.16p x 5 = 0.80p but instead we get 0.78p. My guess is that WooCommerce is calculating the VAT per line and not per item (e.g. 0.13p x 5 = 0.65p and then 0.65p + 20% = 0.78p). See below.[Wrong Amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmaK5.png)

I have tried all sorts of different settings with no success, this is how they are now (see pic attached).[Tax Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT40R.png)

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Have you found a solution? Obviously, I can't launch this with such a bug.. Many thanks!

Comment: I would suggest opening a ticket with WooCommerce. They respond pretty quickly and you should get a more certain answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and post reply/solution back

Comment: WooCommerce tickets get a very fast reply. It seems that its not possible. I have found a way around it by setting the prices including tax, then the correct .80 shows up.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.